# EF Code First multiple 0-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm unable to add a second one-to-many (I'd prefer a zero-to-many)relationship to my class....

I'm also using the Entity First framework. I'm also using a single model with 4 different views. 
2 of them should have a second x-to-many relationship with class A, and the other 2 should have a one-to-many relationship with class B. 
Here's how my classes look:

```
public class Request
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        ... 
        other properties
        ...         
        public virtual ICollection<OrderBasic> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderExtended> ExtendedOrders { get; set; }

    public Request()
    {
        Orders = new List<OrderBasic>();
        ExtendedOrders = new List<OrderExtended>();
    }       
}

public class OrderBasic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }         
    ... 
    specific OrderBasic properties
    ...

    public int RequestRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RequestRefId")]
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}

public class OrderExtended
{
    public int ID { get; set; }         
    ... 
    specific OrderExtended properties
    ...
    public int RequestRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RequestRefId")]
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

**View** which renders a different PartialView depending on the specific type of order I want. Works without issues for the BasicOrder type.

```
@model RFP_MVC.Models.Request

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <legend>General info:</legend>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    //Request Model properties...


        <table class="table table-striped" id="orderTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Material</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="OrderZone">
                @foreach (var row in Model.ExtendedOrders)
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Orders/OrderExtendedCreate.cshtml", row);
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button" id="addOrder">Add order</button>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**DbContext class:**

```
namespace RFP_MVC.DAL
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Shipment> shipments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Request> requests { get; set;  }
        public DbSet<OrderBasic> basicOrders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderExtended> extendedOrders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then generate 4 different views based on a propery requestType. Two views have a collection of OrderBasic, the two other views should implement OrderExtended
I then use a partial view to render properties of the order model. 
As long as I implement just the OrderBasic collection, I have no issues. When I add the second order model (OrderExtended) I receive the following EF related error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Value cannot be null.

The problem appears when I try to display the Index of a certain View, even if it's that of a completely unrelated model (Shipment in this case).

Comment: Something is null in your LINQ query.

Comment: Which LINQ query? I'm even having trouble loading the index of a completely unrelated model. As soon as I comment out the DbSet class of OrderExtended and the list of this class in my Request constructor all is well... No tables get created either. Everything works fine when I just have the single OrderBasic list.

Comment: the code you provided cannot throw `System.ArgumentNullException`, could u debug and bring exact line/code where is exception is thrown.

Comment: I've tried creating a new (much simpler) class with a few random attributes and everything seems to work now, so there must have been something wrong with one of my properties. If all works well I'll submit this as an answer.

Comment: On a side note, don't initialize your collections if you want the lazy loading work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the the culprit. My model contains a file upload:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
```

Which yielded the following error as soon as I tried to add a migration:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet
```

HttpPostedFileBase isn't supported by EF. I'll have to add a property which just stores a reference to the file location, instead of storing the actual file in my DB. Something like this:

```
 [NotMapped]
 [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
 public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment{ get; set; } //file to pass to controller
 public string FilePath { get; set;  } //reference to file path
```

Comment: you can use a bytearray to store binary data in your database. e.g. `public byte[] AttachmentContent {get;set;}`